# tinymce on joomla 1.5 15 filtered html option

Tags: html, editor, tinymce, joomla1.5

I write because I have a problem with the editor TINY mcem 2.0 on joomla 1.5.15
Basically I can not find the settings that allow me to choose the text allow the editor.
Specifically, each time add in an article code:  automatically are deleted.
Someone can help me?
Thank you in advance

Stefania

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tinymce configuration settings valid_elements ans valid_children. You will need to define what elements are treated as valid. Invalid elements get deleted from the editor content.

Comment: unfortunately not enough .... even if I enter the string that I need, after saving and reopening the article, I see that it has saved

Comment: can you describe abit clearer or create a tinymce fiddle of what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: what I want to achieve is to be able to enter the code manually in an article. My current problem is that by entering the code by hand is not saved.

Comment: hmm, difficult to say what the problem is without a live example